# how to make effects happen one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

hi i want to make these events one after another. That means when 1st event ends another events occur. But unable to do so. The 2nd image appears just after first event starts animating Please help me. my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pin01").animate({left: '650px'});

$("#pin01").promise().done(function(x){
$("#pin02").animate({left: '350px'});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img src="mission.gif" id="pin01" style=" position:absolute;top:300px;left:300px;transition:5s"/>
<img src="mission.gif" id="pin02" style=" position:absolute;top:300px;left:900px;transition:5s"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `animate` functions has its own callback function. Use it like this:

```
$("#pin01").animate({left: '650px'}, 500, function() {
    $("#pin02").animate({left: '350px'});
});
```

The 500, is the delay, after the completion of the first animation, you can set it to be 0 if you do not want any delay. And the delay is given in `ms`  (milliseconds).

Comment: why it is not working with 3 images $("#pin01").show().animate({left: '650px'}, 5000, function() {
 $("#pin02").show().animate({left: '350px'}),5000 ,function(){
$("#pin03").show().animate({left: '100px'}),5000 ;
});

});